# python iterate though text file until condition is met

Tags: python, while-loop

i would like to continue iterating through the text file until the current condition inside the loop is met.

here is the sample text:

```
10-01   N/A
10-02   N/A
10-03   N/A
10-04   N/A
10-05   N/A
10-06   N/A
10-07   N/A
10-08   N/A
10-09   N/A
10-10   N/A
10-11   N/A
10-12   N/A
===04===...... # Skip line until '01' is found
===12===...... # Skip line until '01' is found
05-01   N/A
05-02   N/A
05-03   N/A
05-04   N/A
05-05   N/A
05-06   N/A
===08===...... # Skip line until '07' is found
===11===...... # Skip line until '07' is found
05-07   N/A
05-08   N/A
05-09   N/A
05-10   N/A
05-11   N/A
05-12   N/A
```

this is the while loop i am trying:

```
x = 1
with open(loc_path + 'SAMPLEDATA.TXT', 'rb') as textin:
    for line in textin:
        while x < 13:
            if line[3:].startswith(str(x).zfill(2)):
                print '%r' % line
            else:
                x = 1 # Restart loop
            x += 1
```

is there another way to accomplish this besides using a while loop if using a while loop is not correct?

thank you

Comment: Does your current code work properly? It's hard for me to see what you're asking for.

Comment: no it gets stuck infinitely. i tried a few other while loops but they all get stuck. the while loops that finish, print every line in file including lines with '#' which i want to exclude..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change your `while x < 13` into an if-statement to conditionally stop the for-loop. E.g.,

```
x = 1
with open(loc_path + 'SAMPLEDATA.TXT', 'rb') as textin:
    for line in textin:
        if line[3:].startswith(str(x).zfill(2)):
            print '%r' % line
        else:
            x = 1 # Restart counter
        x += 1
        if x >= 13:
            break # Stop reading
```

Comment: Weird this is the accepted answer.  It only goes through the 1-12 counter once (and his example shows multiple sections where the counter would need to be restarted).  Also, what's the point of restarting the counter when the very next line immediately increments it?

Comment: @Gerrat The OP must have gotten his code to work from my suggestion (which is wrong as you indicated) before you posted your answer. He [suggested an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6700423) to my answer to include his code which looked very similar to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You want to:  only increment the counter when you find the line you're looking for, and reset it whenever it hits 13

```
x = 1
with open(loc_path + 'SAMPLEDATA.TXT', 'rb') as textin:
    for line in textin:
        if line[3:].startswith(str(x).zfill(2)):
            print '%r' % line
            x += 1
        if x >= 13:
            x = 1  # reset counter
```

Comment: i added an edit to cpburnz answer which did exactly as you indicated. but you are correct, it only looped once.